# Как перехватить Retrofit запрос

Tags: java, android

```
Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("****")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()
```

> Что нужно сделать чтобы поймать запрос прежде чем данные попадут в
>   addConverterFactory?

---

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient=new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(chain -> {
                    Request request=chain.request();
                    Log.e("RequestApi=init", request.body().toString() + "");
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }).build();

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("****")
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

Вот ошибка `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Использовать `Interceptor`?

Comment: Может я не правильно использую его, но не работает. получаею `null pointer Chain`

Comment: Я давно не использовал Retrofit, скажите `addConverterFactory` обрабатывает ответ или запрос?

Comment: `1)` Нет. Он выдает ошибка что модель не правильно сделана.  `2)` А что вы используете вместо Retrofit?.